# MySQL Union Query w/ Left Join - Order By Error?

Tags: union, sql-order-by

We have a Union Query. Here's a basic (similar) example:

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Info
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON (a.ID = b.ID) 
WHERE a.Name LIKE "a%"
UNION
SELECT a.Name, b.Info 
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b ON (a.ID = b.ID)
WHERE a.Name LIKE "b%"
ORDER BY a.Name, b.Info;
```

I am receiving an error that says "Unknown column 'b.Info' in 'order clause'".

When I remove the "b.Info" from the end of the ORDER BY clause, it works.

Ideas ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Orderby is being applied to the combined result-set - after the Union has taken place.  At this point, there is only one table so to speak, so the reference to b.Info will be invalid.

```
SELECT a.Name AS 'NameCol', b.Info AS 'InfoCol' FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON (a.ID = b.ID) WHERE 
a.Name LIKE "a%" UNION SELECT a.Name AS 'Name', b.Info AS 'Info' FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON
(a.ID = b.ID) WHERE a.Name LIKE "b%" ORDER BY NameCol, InfoCol;
```

Be aware that this could be potentially very slow (with large result sets), as you are forcing MySQL to use a temporary table for the sorting operation.

Comment: This still doesn't justify use of `UNION`.

Comment: In fairness, the question wasn't about if UNION was appropriate or not, it was about issues with manipulating (i.e. ordering) the data set that is generated by a UNION.

Answer (score 3):

This problem is described in the MySQL documentation (12.2.8.3 **UNION** Syntax). You can't use the original table name, so give each column an alias and use this one in the **ORDER BY** clause:

To use an **ORDER BY** or **LIMIT** clause to sort or limit the entire **UNION** result, parenthesize the individual **SELECT** statements and place the **ORDER BY** or **LIMIT** after the last one. The following example uses both clauses:

```
(SELECT a FROM t1 WHERE a=10 AND B=1)
UNION
(SELECT a FROM t2 WHERE a=11 AND B=2)
ORDER BY a LIMIT 10;
```

This kind of **ORDER BY** cannot use column references that include a table name (that is, names in tbl_name.col_name format). Instead, provide a column alias in the first **SELECT** statement and refer to the alias in the **ORDER BY**.

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using union at all? this query is the same and faster:

```
SELECT a.Name, b.Info FROM a LEFT JOIN b ON a.ID = b.ID
WHERE (a.Name LIKE "a%" OR a.Name LIKE "b%") ORDER BY a.Name, b.Info;
```

Read up on parentheses

Answer (score 0):

I think when you're doing `UNION` query you should specify column position, not name in the `ORDER BY` clause. Try `ORDER BY 1,2`.